# How to call the three static methods of the class at one string?

Tags: php, methods, static

Good day! I want to call the methods of my class at one string like this:

```
echo Core::method1()::method2()::method3();
```

But It isn't working!

It's my Class:

```
class Core
{
 public static function method1()
 {
  return new self();
 }
public static function method2()
 {
  return new self();
 }
public static function method3()
 {
 }
}
```

What should I do?

> **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)**

Comment: You can't chain static methods in this way, `method1()`, `method2()` and `method3()` all returning instances, but why don't you simply work with an instance, and instance methods in the first place

Comment: It's badly. Probably, there is another way?

Comment: You must call every one of them in a single statement.

Comment: ok, thank you so much!

Comment: You're returning instances, not sure why.  `echo Core::method1()->method2()->method3();` works but probably not useful.